# Find proportion of a variable within each decile of another variable in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataset:

```
HID     Score   Decile_Name Result
2089    62      4th decile  1
897     47      2nd decile  0
85      55      3rd decile  0
8       74      7th decile  1
23      31      1st decile  1
5657    77      8th decile  1
52      85      9th decile  0
781     63      6th decile  0
565     42      1st decile  0
456     62      4th decile  1
12      89      10th decile 1
56      85      9th decile  1

#Create a DataFrame
df1 = {
     'HID':[2089,897,85,8,23,5657,52,781,565,456,12,56],
    'Score':[62,74,31,77,85,63,42,62,89,85],
    'Decile_Name':['4th decile','7th decile','1st decile','8th decile','9th decile','6th decile','1st decile','4th decile','10th decile','9th decile'],
    'Result' :[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
]}



df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['HID','Score','Decile_Name','Result'])
```

This captures for each student , the Score in a subject and the corresponding Decile of the score. It also captures whether the student has passed or failed(Result)

I want to calculate the proportion of Result = 1 within each Decile(Result %) and overall(in the whole dataset). Expected output:

```
Attribute Level         Result %    num_of_stu  
Score - All Categories  0.5         12 # This captures the values for the whole df(df1).
Score - 1st Decile      0.5         2
Score - 2nd Decile      0           1
Score - 3rd Decile      0           1
...
Score - 9th Decile      0.5         2
Score - 10th Decile     1           1
```

Can someone please help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution if `0` and `1` values only in `Result` column:

First aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), then sorting index values by integers by [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.argsort.html), create new summary DataFrame and [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) it:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Decile_Name').agg({'Result':'mean', 'HID':'size'})
df1 = df1.iloc[df1.index.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).argsort()]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Result': [df['Result'].mean()],
                    'HID': [len(df)]}, index=['All Categories'])

d = {'Result':'Result %','HID':'num_of_stu'}
df1 = df2.append(df1).rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
                Result %  num_of_stu
All Categories  0.583333          12
1st decile      0.500000           2
2nd decile      0.000000           1
3rd decile      0.000000           1
4th decile      1.000000           2
6th decile      0.000000           1
7th decile      1.000000           1
8th decile      1.000000           1
9th decile      0.500000           2
10th decile     1.000000           1
```

General solution - create boolena mask only for `1` values:

```
df['Result1'] = df['Result'] == 1
df1 = df.groupby('Decile_Name').agg({'Result1':'mean', 'HID':'size'})
df1 = df1.iloc[df1.index.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).argsort()]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Result1': [df['Result1'].mean()],
                  'HID': [len(df)]}, index=['All Categories'])

d = {'Result1':'Result %','HID':'num_of_stu'}
df1 = df2.append(df1).rename(columns=d)
print (df1)
                Result %  num_of_stu
All Categories  0.583333          12
1st decile      0.500000           2
2nd decile      0.000000           1
3rd decile      0.000000           1
4th decile      1.000000           2
6th decile      0.000000           1
7th decile      1.000000           1
8th decile      1.000000           1
9th decile      0.500000           2
10th decile     1.000000           1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#build mean of Results grouped by Decile Name
result_df = df1[['Decile_Name','Result']].groupby(['Decile_Name']).mean()

#build count of Students grouped by Decile Name
students_df = df1[['Decile_Name','HID']].groupby(['Decile_Name']).count()

#merge the two dataframes
merged_df = pd.concat([result_df, students_df], axis=1)

#Add the sum for all studends as Index "All Students"
merged_df.loc["All Studends"] = [df1[['Result']].mean()["Result"], df1[['HID']].count()["HID"]]

#print 
print(merged_df)
```

Result:

```
                 Result     HID
Decile_Name         
10th decile     1.000000    1.0
1st decile  0.500000    2.0
2nd decile  0.000000    1.0
3rd decile  0.000000    1.0
4th decile  1.000000    2.0
6th decile  0.000000    1.0
7th decile  1.000000    1.0
8th decile  1.000000    1.0
9th decile  0.500000    2.0
All Studends    0.583333    12.0
```